# VirtualBox installation problem on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: virtualbox

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

Is there any solution to this problem?  the sudo /sbin/vboxconfig command isnt working too, also my system is not using EFI Secure Boot. Thanks

Comment: When you execute `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` do you see error messages?

Comment: yes it says : vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.   And then again it says:

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

Comment: This solved it for me: https://superuser.com/a/1513506/628839

Answer (score 8):

If you have recently received a kernel update, then you may need to reinstall the `virtualbox-dkms` package:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms --reinstall
```

Once installed, verify the kernel module is active with:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: while installing the virtualbox-dkms i get this error: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module. And when i type the command sudo modprobe vboxdrv i get this error: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted

Comment: It sure sounds like secure boot is active.

Comment: This method worked for me, And DKMS: install completed.

Comment: I have the same problem as Moustafa. 
secure boot must be active or inactive?

Comment: @asteriogonzalez Disabled,always, unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11 that requires it.  Use MOK in that case: https://askubuntu.com/a/1396818/1210606

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by doing following on ubuntu 20.04:

- Method 1: sudo apt-get install virtualbox
- Method 2: install software center (the software center is not loading by default on my computer), and install virtualbox from there.

However, no matter what, Error occurs “Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module”

Solution:
found from : https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-20-04/

1. `sudo reboot`
2. Choose Enroll MOK » Continue » Yes » Enter Password (you have set earlier) » Reboot.